# Creating the Cover Flow effect like Apple with jQuery

Tags: jquery, coverflow

I'm looking to recreate apple's cover flow effect using jQuery.

I've looked at some various options and came across:

- ImageFlow -> http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/ (just javascript, not jQuery)
- cFlow -> http://blarnee.com/wp/cflow-coverflow-for-jquery-experimental-release/
- xFlow! -> http://www.pwhitrow.com/blog/entries/2009/04/06/xflow-a-javascript-and-php-based-coverflow-style-gallery/ (not jQuery)

And that is it so far. Each of which have various positives. ImageFlow looks a bit large script wise and I'm wondering if anybody has seen a jQuery port of it. I did find a guy who's patched it for Drupal using jQuery @ http://drupal.org/node/373591, but its just that - a patch to run over the top and swap standard js events to jQuery ones.

Have you come across any better ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI:

xFlow! is built with standard Javascript and PHP.

For the latest version and more information, please visit http://xflow.pwhitrow.com